# gRPC message format

Tags: grpc, codec

I'd like to know how to properly construct GRPC REQUEST and RESPONSE. There are only two resources that I found on the "codec" part:

- Encoding: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding
- HTTP/2: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md#message-encoding

I believe I understand both documents. I understand how the HTTP/2 framing works (I implemented my own HTTP/2 server and client in Rust so I understand it in detail) but the sent message is always somehow invalid.

Let's take for an example this simple message (proto3):

```
message Test1 {
  int32 a = 1;
}
```

I'm dealing with the RESPONSE part only for now. The wire format for value `150` (as specified in the google's example) should be Hex[08, 96, 01] ([00001000, 10010110, 00000001]). I pack this into a DATA frame and send it as a RESPONSE back to the GRPC client. Here's what the response looks like:

```sh
...
[  0.010] recv SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=0)
00000000  00 00 00 04 01 00 00 00  00                       |.........|
00000009
[  0.010] recv SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
          ; ACK
          (niv=0)
[  0.010] send SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
          ; ACK
          (niv=0)
00000000  00 00 0e 01 04 00 00 00  0d 88 5f 8b 1d 75 d0 62  |.........._..u.b|
00000010  0d 26 3d 4c 4d 65 64                              |.&=LMed|
00000017
[  0.012] recv (stream_id=13) :status: 200
[  0.012] recv (stream_id=13) content-type: application/grpc
[  0.012] recv HEADERS frame <length=14, flags=0x04, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
          ; First response header
00000000  00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00  0d 08 96 01              |............|
0000000c
[  0.016] recv DATA frame <length=3, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
00000000  00 00 0f 01 05 00 00 00  0d 40 0b 67 72 70 63 2d  |.........@.grpc-|
00000010  73 74 61 74 75 73 81 07                           |status..|
00000018
[  0.016] recv (stream_id=13) grpc-status: 0
[  0.016] recv HEADERS frame <length=15, flags=0x05, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM | END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
[  0.021] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (last_stream_id=0, error_code=NO_ERROR(0x00), opaque_data(0)=[])
```

There must be a missing header or I'm missing the message format. Can someone please post a working example using `curl`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that the `Length-Prefixed-Message` is actually `Length-Prefixed, Message` so every DATA payload must be prefixed.